# Setting up SharePoint 2013 for apps development - apps DNS setting

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, dns

I have installed WinServer 2012 RC2, MS SQL Dev 2012 and SP13 with Service Pack1. I have setup my apps from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515677/MyplusFirstplusSharepoint-HostedplusAppplusinplus2). I have my "Sharepoint PC" connected to LAN. I can access sharepoint server and sites from another PC just by typing "http://mySPServer/sites/dev". But when I deploy add-in(app) and it tries to load up for ex. "http://dev-623236236.myapps.com" it is accesible only on "Sharepoint PC", but not on my LAN. Please, how can I setup my DNS setting so I can also access apps domain. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved the issue:

1 ) go to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc

```
 open the hosts file and set the dynamic IP of your machine facing you site url

 example 10.120.54.182  momo.at.morocco
```

2) save and try again, it works